# Adding custom footer in title page using latex without using any package

Tags: header-footer

I am trying to add a footer to every page. The following code is working except the title page. I do not want to use any package. So, how can i do that?

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ps@edbfooter}{
   \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{my footer\hfill}%     
   \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{my footer}%     
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question. I want to show the same footer for title page too. How can I do that?

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: I think a MWE would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most practical solution is to issue `\thispagestyle{edbfooter}` after `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 1):

Since I assume that `\pagestyle{edbfooter}` is being issued, another option would be to use `\let\ps@plain\ps@edbfooter` inside `\makeatletter`, and `\makeatother`.